# Connecting Buttons which are added using interface Builder using code - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created 4 buttons via Interface Builder. I have an array which has the following content stored in it

```
"A"
"B"
"B"
"A"
```

Now what i need to do is to read the `array` of strings and paint the button `Yellow` or `Red`. If the String is `A` then the button should be `Yellow`, and if the String character is `B` the button should be `Red`.

My code so far;

```
for (NSString* content in arr) {
           if ([content isEqualToString:@"A"]){
               // Make the (1st/there after) button in the interface builder to Yellow and etc 
           }else {
// Make the 1st button in the interface builder to Redand etc
}
       }
```

Comment: You have more strings than buttons?

Comment: Sorry, typo. i have updated my question.

Comment: What did you mean - _paint the button_? Do you have these 4 button on your screen or want to create new?

Comment: I have added 4 buttons using IB on the screen. Now if the String (in the array) is "A" i need to change the color of the button to Yellow, and if the string is "B" to change the color of the button to Red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in Interface Builder (IB) you need to assign tag's to each button that you want to change so that you can retrieve them later.  Set the first button tag to 0, second to 1, etc.

Then your code would look something like this:

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
    if ([(NSString *)[arr objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    } else {
        [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should tag the buttons in IB, or create Outlets for them in the subclass. Then you can reference them by these tags or outlets.

Once you have created all of the outlets, you could store the references in a member variable containing the outlets. Then it is a simple matter of setting the background color to the correct value based on the string.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use `tag` property of `UIButton`. Suppose, your button tags will be `1, 2, 3, 4.` So:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"B", @"A", nil];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    UIView *view = [self.view viewWithTag:i + 1];
    if ([[array objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"A"])
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    else if ([[array objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"B"])
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Besides, I wouldn't recommend you to use IB, especially at the beginning. Write the code by yourself.
This code may contain syntax or logic errors (I wrote it in notepad):

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

//

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A", @"B", @"B", @"A", nil];
    CGFloat offset = 5.0f, step = self.view.frame.size.width / [array count];
    for (NSString *string in array) {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(offset, 5, step - 10, 50);
        offset += step;

        if ([string isEqualToString:@"A"])
            button.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        else if ([string isEqualToString:@"B"])
            button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        [self.view addSubview:button];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Recommending against IB is a terrible practice. IB is created for developers of all skill levels. The Apple developers 100% use this technology and that means you should use it too. Creating interfaces through code is inaccurate, troublesome, and extremely difficult to maintain.

Comment: It's just my opinion. "The Apple developers 100% use this technology and that means you should use it too." - I don't think, you are right. Using IB also have negative sides. Everyone chooses by himself. I don't force anyone not to use IB.

Comment: Name one negative side? The official developers do use this technology, that is a fact. Why makes you think you are a better developer than them? Why make life hard on yourself?

Comment: 1. Slow & resource-demanding screen loading;
2. Difficulties with code debugging;
3. It's pretty hard to make smth non-standard.

They may use any thing they want. I don't care about this. Also I don't make my life harder with this - writing the code is more handy for me.

P.S. Looking at number of bugs in last versions of MacOS, iOS and (especially!) XCode, I wouldn't attain to the level of them ;)

Comment: 1. IB loads binary files, this has the same overhead as creating your interface in code. 2. Debugging with LLDB has no bearing on how your objects were loaded in to memory. 3. Interface Builder supports any custom subclass. P.S. Writing code by hand will **ALWAYS** be more work than using code generated by a tool (IB). You have presented quite a feeble argument.

Comment: 1. Actually, .nib/.xib files, which IB creates, are XML files. So it take a time to parse it and load to screen. 2. But as for me, it's easier to find the bug, when I wrote all of it by myself and totally know, how it works. 3. OK, I might be wrong here. I attempted to do this just once. I don't argue with fact, that writing code by yourself is more complicated and takes more time, but I prefer exactly this way. Again: I don't force anyone not to use IB. And I have see no reasons to continue this discussion.

Comment: I really don't want to continue this discussion either, just need to point out you are still spreading wrong information. .XIB files are XML in XCode but are converted to binary .NIB files as part of the build process. This means they are literally in memory versions of your views, but frozen and written to disk. Review the Apple documentation on this, but they are absolutely **NOT** parsed as XML every time a view is loaded.

Comment: This discussion between you two were very helpful for me in understanding certain stuff. Thank you both of you.